# How to traverse an inner array in motoko?

Tags: motoko, internet-computer, dfinity

I am new to Motoko and internet computer, when I am working I am having too much difficulties that might look simple, I am having difficulties doing this, posting the link to forum question here

https://forum.dfinity.org/t/how-to-traverse-inner-array-of-a-trie/12941?u=manubodhi

Please help if somebody is well versed in Motoko and Dfinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared a small code in motoko playground for you in order to see how you can traverse inner array and achieve your goal of filtering Trie. Here is as well saved project in motoko playground: https://m7sm4-2iaaa-aaaab-qabra-cai.raw.ic0.app/?tag=1150943578

Shortly to filter through inner array you can use:

```
let trieOfDishes = Trie.filter<DishId, Dish>(dishes, func (k, v) {
    Array.find<MealTypeId>(v.mealTypeId, func(x : MealTypeId) { x == mealTypeId }) != null ;
});
```

Full code of canister implementation:

```
import Trie "mo:base/Trie";
import Array "mo:base/Array";
import Iter "mo:base/Iter";
import Nat32 "mo:base/Nat32";

actor Dishes {
    
    type DishId = Nat32;
    type DishTypeId = Nat32;
    type MealTypeId = Nat32;

    public type Dish = {
        dishId: DishId;
        dishTypeId : DishTypeId;
        mealTypeId : [MealTypeId]
    };

    var dishes: Trie.Trie<DishId, Dish> = Trie.empty();

    private func key(x : DishId) : Trie.Key<DishId> {
        return { hash = x; key = x };
    };
    
    public func add_dish(dish: Dish) : async Dish {
        dishes := Trie.replace(dishes, key(dish.dishId), Nat32.equal, ?dish).0;
        return dish;
    };

    public query func getDishesByDishId (dishTypeId : DishTypeId) : async [(DishId, Dish)] {
       let trieOfDishes = Trie.filter<DishId, Dish>(dishes, func (k, v) { v.dishId == dishTypeId } );
       let arrayOfDishes : [(DishId, Dish)] = Iter.toArray(Trie.iter(trieOfDishes));
       return arrayOfDishes;
    };

    public query func getDishesBymealTypeId (mealTypeId : MealTypeId) : async [(DishId, Dish)] {
       let trieOfDishes = Trie.filter<DishId, Dish>(dishes, func (k, v) {
            Array.find<MealTypeId>(v.mealTypeId, func(x : MealTypeId) { x == mealTypeId }) != null ;
       });
       let arrayOfDishes : [(DishId, Dish)] = Iter.toArray(Trie.iter(trieOfDishes));
       return arrayOfDishes;
    };
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I actually want to learn all these! which projects you tried to learn all these, i am struggling with the poor documentation and lack of intermediate examples in motoko. Thank you once again :)

Comment: No problem, Unfortunately sometimes documentation of motoko is hard to read through since it is in various different places and there could be a little bit more useful sample projects.
I would recommend playing over in motoko playground if you're stuck with some problems and try to do it as easily as possible. Sometimes you can find some demo projects from DFINITY to get some inspiration if you stuck :)